# Loaders with Paginated Listview

Tags: android, listview, pagination, loader

I am using Loader implementation with AsynTaskLoader and Matrixcursor. Also implemented paginated listview. When user scrolls, I get to use restartloader function; yet it discards the current data and restarts loading the whole list and reloads them all over again.

Getting the data by using LIMIT keyword of SQL. Everytime I use reload function LIMIT value is increased by 10. Thus, everytime I use the restartloader function, it discards all it has and reloads what discarded and another 10.

I feel like I could add up to the current matrixcursor. Is this bad implementation? Is there any better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, loadMoreItemsToList(), callbacks);
    }
}
```

Here is the loadMoreItemsToList function:

```
Bundle loadMoreItemsToList(){
    isLoadingItems = true;
    itemCountInList += 10;
    bundle.putInt("ItemCount", itemCountInList);
    return bundle;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what is "paginated listview" first so as others can help..

Comment: Listview that loads more items when scrolled to the end of the list.

Comment: I see.. In this case, I think its better you implement your own `AsyncTask` to fetch the data and initiate it in your `onScroll` method (replace `restartLoader`). Finally, append the new items to your adapter in `onPostExecute(...)` method.

Comment: I am quite obsessed with Loaders and most of the time I prefer to use them instead of AsyncTask. But I guess this is the time I should prefer AsyncTask. Thanks for the help.